# Qt Split QString once

Tags: c++, qt, split, qstring, qtcore

I want to split a `QString`, but according to the documentation, the split function only allows for splitting whenever the character to split at occurs. What I want  is to only split at the place where first time the character occurs.

For example:

`5+6+7` wiht default `split()` would end in a list containing `["5","6","7"]`

what I want: a list with only two elements -> `["5","6+7"]`

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Okay... what have you tried?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I went online and searched for it but didnt find something on forums or the qt documentation. It´s more that I want to know if theres a stock/native function that can do what i suggest.

Comment: Use `indexOf` to find the first occurrence of `"+"`. Then split the string using `mid` - `mid(0,index)` and `mid(index+1)`

Comment: It doesnt have to be native function to get your job done about anything. You can take the first element from array and join the rest.

Comment: So much for one-time users who come, and do not follow up anymore... :(

Answer (score 17):

There are various ways to achieve this, but [this is](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#section) likely and arguably the simplest:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QString string("5+6+7");
    qDebug() << string.section('+', 0, 0) << string.section('+', 1);
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
"5" "6+7"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf()` to find the first occurrence of "+". Then split the string using mid - `mid(0,index)` and `mid(index+1)` – credit to "R Sahu"